# Defining templated constant variables in cuda

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, cuda

How do I implement templated constant variable in `cuda`. I have a `struct`

```
template<typename T> mystruct{ T d1; T d2[10];}
```

I want to have a constant variable with the above `struct` and use a code something like below (code may not be correct at this point)

```
template<typename T> __constant__ mystruct<T> const_data;
```

after this within main I want to copy some

```
  mystruct<float> data;
```

into `const_data`  and eventually access it within device code. It would be kind if someone points out how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forget to initialize your constant `data` structure. You are also forgetting `struct` and its terminating semicolon.

Comment: is that the only error in my code ? that is if i initialize data struct it will work ? please explain a bit more i am new to cuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CUDA, `__constant__` variables have implied static storage. It isn't clear from your question at what point you would want to instantiate the constant memory variable, but given that constant memory variables are static and need to be declared and used within the same translation unit in the standard compilation model, your options are pretty limited.

There is nothing stopping you from defining a templated type and then statically defining a particular instance of that type  in constant memory, for example:

```
template<typename T> struct mystruct{ T d1; T d2[10]; };

__constant__ mystruct<float> const_data;
```

But, to the best of my knowledge, that is all you can do.